# webapp to desktop conversion issue using nightrain

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new here on Stackoverflow and this is my first question. I've searched here from the various questions if it's possible to create native desktop applications based on the web language php that is my specialization.

I've found some topic that talk about a github repository called nightrain. I've decided to download it to give a try, and I've also updated the php script version to the 7.2.10 but every time i try to start the `build.py` script, on my mac console will be printed an error. I'm not expert with the python, so I would ask if someone can help me to solve this issue, I've googled a bit but there aren't documentations about this script.

Here is the reported error

> yur$ python /Users/yur/Desktop/nightrain-master/build.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/yur/Desktop/nightrain-master/build.py", line 19, in 
> compiler.compile_nightrain_mac()
> File "/Users/yur/Desktop/nightrain-master/Classes/Compiler.py", line 179, in compile_nightrain_mac
> call(["pyinstaller.py", "--clean", "-w", "-y", "-F", spec_path, application_icon, "-n", "nightrain", "Application.py"])
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
> return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
> errread, errwrite)
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

And this is the code of the build.py script

```
from Classes.Compiler import Compiler
from Classes.Settings import Settings

settings = Settings()
compiler = Compiler("./dist", "./nrtmp", "./Resources")

# clean output folder
compiler.clean_dist()

# compile nightrain

if compiler.is_windows():
    compiler.compile_nightrain_windows()

if compiler.is_linux():
    compiler.compile_nightrain_linux()

if compiler.is_mac():
    compiler.compile_nightrain_mac()

# compile PHP

if compiler.is_windows():
    compiler.compile_php_windows()

if compiler.is_linux():
    compiler.compile_php_linux()

if compiler.is_mac():
    compiler.compile_php_mac()

# copy required files

if compiler.is_windows():
    compiler.copy_resources()
    compiler.copy_php_windows()
    settings.create_default_settings(compiler.get_settings_ini_dest())

if compiler.is_linux():
    compiler.copy_resources()
    compiler.copy_php_linux()
    compiler.copy_php_ini_linux()
    settings.create_default_settings(compiler.get_settings_ini_dest())

if compiler.is_mac():
    app_version_dir = "%s/%s" % (compiler.output_dir, "app_version")
    shell_version_dir = "%s/%s" % (compiler.output_dir, "shell_version")

    nightrain_app_file_dest = "%s/nightrain.app" % app_version_dir
    nightrain_shell_file_dest = "%s/nightrain" % shell_version_dir

    nightrain_app_file_source = "%s/nightrain.app" % compiler.output_dir
    nightrain_shell_file_source = "%s/nightrain" % compiler.output_dir

    # create the output directories
    compiler.make_dir(app_version_dir)
    compiler.make_dir(shell_version_dir)

    # move nightrain.app to app version dir
    compiler.move_file(nightrain_app_file_source, nightrain_app_file_dest)

    # move nightrain shell version to shell version dir
    compiler.move_file(nightrain_shell_file_source, nightrain_shell_file_dest)

    # copy PHP libraries to app version
    destination = "%s/Contents/MacOS/lib/php" % nightrain_app_file_dest
    compiler.copy_php_mac(destination)

    # copy PHP libraries to shell version
    destination = "%s/lib/php" % shell_version_dir
    compiler.copy_php_mac(destination)

    # copy resources to app version
    mac_os_x_dir = "%s/Contents/MacOS" % nightrain_app_file_dest
    compiler.copy_resources(mac_os_x_dir)
    settings.create_default_settings("%s/%s" % (mac_os_x_dir, "settings.ini"))

    # copy resources to shell version
    compiler.copy_resources(shell_version_dir)
    settings.create_default_settings("%s/%s" % (shell_version_dir, "settings.ini"))

    # copy PHP ini to app version
    destination = "%s/Contents/MacOS/lib/php/bin/php.ini" % nightrain_app_file_dest
    compiler.copy_php_ini_mac(destination)

    # copy php ini to app version
    destination = "%s/lib/php/bin/php.ini" % shell_version_dir
    compiler.copy_php_ini_mac(destination)
```

This is the Compiler.py script code

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
import urllib
import zipfile
import Settings

from subprocess import call

class Compiler:

    build_dir = "./build"
    output_dir = "./dist"
    tmp_dir = "./nrtmp"
    resources_dir = "./resources"
    php_linux_binary_dir = "/home/naetech/php"
    php_mac_binary_dir = "/Users/naetech/php"
    php_windows_binary_dir = "C:\\nightrain_php"

    def __init__(self, output_dir, tmp_dir, resources_dir):
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        self.tmp_dir = tmp_dir
        self.resources_dir = resources_dir

    @staticmethod
    def is_linux():

        platform = sys.platform
        if "linux" in platform:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def is_windows():
        if "win" in sys.platform and "darwin" not in sys.platform:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def is_mac():
        if "darwin" in sys.platform:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def compile_php_windows(self):
        # remove the old binary
        if os.path.exists(self.php_windows_binary_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.php_windows_binary_dir)

        # create a random tmp directory
        if os.path.exists(self.tmp_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir)

        os.mkdir(self.tmp_dir)
        # Non thread safe 64bit vers https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.2.10-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
        # Thread safe 32bit vers https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.2.10-Win32-VC15-x86.zip
        # download the latest version of PHP
        php_file_zip_download_link = "https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.2.10-Win32-VC15-x86.zip"
        php_file_zip_dest = "%s/%s" % (self.tmp_dir, "php-7.2.10-Win32-VC15-x86.zip")
        print "Downloading %s" % php_file_zip_download_link
        urllib.urlretrieve(php_file_zip_download_link, php_file_zip_dest)
        print "Finished downloading %s" % php_file_zip_download_link

        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(php_file_zip_dest)
        for name in zfile.namelist():
            (dirname, filename) = os.path.split(name)
            extracted_dir = "%s\\%s" % (self.php_windows_binary_dir, dirname)
            print "Decompressing " + filename + " on " + dirname
            if not os.path.exists(extracted_dir):
                os.makedirs(extracted_dir)
            zfile.extract(name, extracted_dir)

        return True

    def compile_php_mac(self):
        # remove the old binary
        if os.path.exists(self.php_mac_binary_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.php_mac_binary_dir)

        # create a random tmp directory
        if os.path.exists(self.tmp_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir)

        os.mkdir(self.tmp_dir)

        # download the latest version of PHP
        php_tar_file_save_location = "%s/%s" % (self.tmp_dir, "php7210.tar.gz")
        # fixme add a config file so the developers can update this link without modifying the source codes
        # http://us1.php.net/get/php-7.2.10.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
        php_tar_download_link = "http://us1.php.net/get/php-7.2.10.tar.gz/from/this/mirror"
        self.download_file(php_tar_download_link, php_tar_file_save_location)

        php_extracted_dir = "%s/%s" % (self.tmp_dir, "php7210")
        os.mkdir(php_extracted_dir)
        call(["tar", "-C", php_extracted_dir, "-zxvf", php_tar_file_save_location])

        # compile PHP
        php_source_dir = "%s/%s" % (php_extracted_dir, "php-7.2.10")

        configure_command = "cd %s && ./configure --prefix=%s " \
                           "--enable-bcmath " \
                           "--enable-calendar " \
                           "--enable-mbstring " \
                           "--with-curl " \
                           "--with-gd " \
                           "--with-mysql " \
                           "--with-pdo-mysql " \
                           "--with-sqlite3" \
                           % (php_source_dir, self.php_mac_binary_dir)
        call(configure_command, shell=True)

        make_command = "cd %s && make && make install" % php_source_dir
        call(make_command, shell=True)

        return True

    def compile_php_linux(self):

        # remove the old binary
        if os.path.exists(self.php_linux_binary_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.php_linux_binary_dir)

        # create a random tmp directory
        if os.path.exists(self.tmp_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir)

        os.mkdir(self.tmp_dir)

        # download the latest version of PHP
        phpTarFile = "%s/%s" % (self.tmp_dir, "php7210.tar.gz")
        call(["wget", "http://us1.php.net/get/php-7.2.10.tar.gz/from/this/mirror", "-O", phpTarFile])

        phpDir = "%s/%s" % (self.tmp_dir, "php7210")
        os.mkdir(phpDir)
        call(["tar", "-C", phpDir, "-zxvf", phpTarFile])

        # compile PHP
        phpSourceDir = "%s/%s" % (phpDir, "php-7.2.10")

        configureCommand = "cd %s && ./configure --prefix=%s " \
                           "--enable-bcmath " \
                           "--enable-calendar " \
                           "--enable-mbstring " \
                           "--with-curl " \
                           "--with-gd " \
                           "--with-mysql " \
                           "--with-pdo-mysql " \
                           "--with-sqlite3" \
                           % (phpSourceDir, self.php_linux_binary_dir)
        call(configureCommand, shell=True)

        makeCommand = "cd %s && make && make install" % (phpSourceDir)
        call(makeCommand, shell=True)

        return True

    def compile_nightrain_windows(self):
        self.clean_unncessary_files()
        spec_path = "--specpath=%s/%s" % (self.build_dir, "specs")
        application_icon = "--icon=%s/%s" % (self.resources_dir, "icon.ico")
        # fixme When using the -w option, the final executable causes error
        call(["pyinstaller.py", "--clean", "-y", "-F", spec_path, application_icon, "-n", "nightrain", "Application.py"],
             shell=True)
        self.clean_unncessary_files()

    def compile_nightrain_linux(self):
        self.clean_unncessary_files()
        spec_path = "--specpath=%s/%s" % (self.build_dir, "specs")
        call(["pyinstaller", "--clean", "-y", "-F", spec_path, "-n", "nightrain", "Application.py"])
        self.clean_unncessary_files()

    def compile_nightrain_mac(self):
        self.clean_unncessary_files()
        spec_path = "--specpath=%s/%s" % (self.build_dir, "specs")
        application_icon = "--icon=%s/%s" % (self.resources_dir, "icon.ico")
        call(["pyinstaller.py", "--clean", "-w", "-y", "-F", spec_path, application_icon, "-n", "nightrain", "Application.py"])
        self.clean_unncessary_files()

    def make_dir(self, path):
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            try:
                os.mkdir(path)
                print "Successfully created: %s" % path
                return True
            except:
                print "Could not create %s" % path
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def move_file(self, source, destination):
        if os.path.exists(source):
            try:
                shutil.move(source, destination)
                print "Successfully moved %s to %s" % (source, destination)
                return True
            except:
                print "Could not move %s to %s" % (source, destination)
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def copy_file(self, source, destination):
        success_msg = "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (source, destination)
        failure_msg = "Could not copy %s to %s" % (source, destination)

        if os.path.exists(source) and os.path.isdir(source):
            try:
                shutil.copytree(source, destination)
                print success_msg
                return True
            except:
                print failure_msg
                return False
        elif os.path.exists(source) and os.path.isfile(source):
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
                print success_msg
                return True
            except:
                print failure_msg
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def copy_resources(self, custom_output_dir=None):

        items = [
            "www",
            "icon.png",
            "LICENSE"
        ]

        for item in items:
            if item == "icon.png" and (self.is_windows() or self.is_mac()):
                continue

            source = "%s/%s" % (self.resources_dir, item)
            if not custom_output_dir:
                destination = "%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, item)
            else:
                destination = "%s/%s" % (custom_output_dir, item)
            if os.path.exists(source):
                error = "Could not copy item %s" % (item)
                success = "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (source, destination)
                if os.path.isfile(source):
                    try:
                        shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
                        print success
                    except:
                        print error
                        return False
                else:
                    try:
                        shutil.copytree(source, destination)
                        print success
                    except:
                        print error
                        return False
            else:
                print "%s does not exist" % (item)
                return False

    def copy_php_windows(self):
        destination = "%s/%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, "lib", "php")
        if os.path.exists(self.php_windows_binary_dir):
            try:
                shutil.copytree(self.php_windows_binary_dir, destination)
                print "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (self.php_windows_binary_dir, destination)
                return True
            except:
                print "Could not copy %s to %s" % (self.php_windows_binary_dir, destination)
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def copy_php_mac(self, destination_dir):
        if not self.copy_file(self.php_mac_binary_dir, destination_dir):
            return False
        return True

    def copy_php_linux(self):
        destination = "%s/%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, "lib", "php")
        if os.path.exists(self.php_linux_binary_dir):
            try:
                shutil.copytree(self.php_linux_binary_dir, destination)
                print "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (self.php_linux_binary_dir, destination)
                return True
            except:
                print "Could not copy %s to %s" % (self.php_linux_binary_dir, destination)
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def copy_php_ini_linux(self):
        src = "%s/%s" % (self.resources_dir, "php.ini")
        destination = self.get_php_ini_dest()
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(src, destination)
            print "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (src, destination)
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def copy_php_ini_windows(self):
        php_ini_src = "%s\\%s" % (self.php_windows_binary_dir, "php.ini-production")
        php_ini_dest = self.get_php_ini_dest()
        if os.path.exists(php_ini_src):
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(php_ini_src, php_ini_dest)
                print "Successfully copied %s to %s" % (php_ini_src, php_ini_dest)

                # replace configs
                php_ini_configs = [
                    '; extension_dir = "ext"',
                    ';extension=php_gd2.dll',
                    ';extension=php_mbstring.dll',
                    ';extension=php_sqlite3.dll'
                ]

                for config in php_ini_configs:
                    config_uncommented = config.replace(";", "").strip()
                    Settings.Settings.replace(php_ini_dest, config, config_uncommented)
                    print "Replaced %s with %s in %s" % (config, config_uncommented, php_ini_dest)
                return True
            except:
                return False
        else:
            print "Could not find %s" % php_ini_src

    def copy_php_ini_mac(self, dest):
        source = "%s/settings.ini" % self.resources_dir
        return self.copy_file(source, dest)

    def clean_dist(self):

        if os.path.exists(self.output_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.output_dir)

    def clean_unncessary_files(self):

        if os.path.exists(self.tmp_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir)

        if os.path.exists(self.build_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(self.build_dir)

    def remove_file(self, file_path):
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)

    def get_php_ini_dest(self):
        if self.is_linux() or self.is_mac():
            return "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, "lib", "php", "bin", "php.ini")
        elif self.is_windows():
            return "%s/%s/%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, "lib", "php", "php.ini")
        else:
            return False

    def get_settings_ini_dest(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (self.output_dir, "settings.ini")

    def download_file(self, download_link, where_to_save_file_including_file_name):
        print "Downloading %s" % download_link
        urllib.urlretrieve(download_link, where_to_save_file_including_file_name)
        print "Finished downloading %s" % download_link
        print "File saved to %s" % download_link
```

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies installed? It looks like it cannot run `pyinstaller.py`.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure it's a good idea to use that tool. It hasn't been updated for 4 years, it doesn't have any documentation, creator's website doesn't exist anymore... Sure, you may be successful and make it work but you probably don't get any support.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy How i can check if pyinstaller is available on my machine?I'm not sure about this and macOS 10.13.5 is locked and doesn't permit to install using the pip installer command any dependencies.

Comment: What about trying to run it? Why you shouldn't be able to install packages using `pip`? You don't have an administrator account on your system?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy this is the error message i get when i try to install using pip `macholib 1.11 has requirement altgraph>=0.15, but you'll have altgraph 0.10.2 which is incompatible.` I've used the `pip install --user <package>` command, now this is the only problem I have with this dependency.

Comment: OK. Then you will have to fix it I'm afraid.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I've fixed the error about dependencies, but I've the same problem. I've started thinking that there is an error in the python code?